# jQuery parseXML() no longer works since Summer '18

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service, xmlparsing, summer-18

Since the Summer '18 patch the jQuery parseXML() is now throwing a "Invalid XML: .." error message. Sample code:

```
try{
    var xml = "<node>test</node>";
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    console.log(xmlDoc);
}catch(e){
    console.error(e.message);
}
```

Console output:

```
Invalid XML: <node>test</node>
```

The jQuery version we are using is v2.2.4 which I believe is the most Locker Service compatible version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LockerService team has been notified of this issue in the Summer 18 release. We have fixed the bug in a patch release. The fix is scheduled to rollout to production starting 5/9/2018 and may be take a couple of days to reach all instances.

The root cause was a regression in support for DOMParser.

The bug record is W-4954203, incase you want to reference it in a customer case etc.